# Sending photo from URL with Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot which sends photo upon request from URL using pyTelegramBotAPI wrapper. So I tried putting a dummy photo URL and test if the bot can send the image but it failed with the following error.

`telebot.apihelper.ApiException: sendPhoto failed. Returned result: <Response [400]>`

I'm not sure what the error is, but how can I send a photo from URL using Telegram Bot API correctly? Here is my code

```
import telebot
import time
import urllib
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

TOKEN = '<token here>'
url='http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/e15/10919672_584633251672188_179950734_n.jpg'

def listener(*messages):
    for m in messages:
        chatid = m.chat.id
        if m.content_type == 'text':
            text = m.text
            name = m.fromUser.first_name
            msgid = m.message_id
            if(text.startswith('/photo')):
                img = BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
                tb.send_chat_action(chatid, 'upload_photo')
                tb.send_photo(chatid, img, reply_to_message_id=msgid)


tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
tb.get_update()  # cache exist message
tb.set_update_listener(listener) #register listener
tb.polling()
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm not sure whether I missed something though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
import telebot
import time
import urllib

url = 'http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/e15/10919672_584633251672188_179950734_n.jpg'
f = open('out.jpg','wb')
f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
f.close()

def listener(*messages):
    for m in messages:
        chat_id = m.chat.id
        if m.content_type == 'text':
            text = m.text
            msgid = m.message_id
            if text.startswith('/photo'):
                tb.send_chat_action(chat_id, 'upload_photo')
                img = open('out.jpg', 'rb')
                tb.send_photo(chat_id, img, reply_to_message_id=msgid)
                img.close()


tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
tb.set_update_listener(listener) #register listener
tb.polling()

while True:
    time.sleep(0)
```

or (using pyTelegramBotAPI 0.2.0)

```
import telebot
import time
import urllib

url='http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/e15/10919672_584633251672188_179950734_n.jpg'
f = open('out.jpg','wb')
f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
f.close()

tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@tb.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def send_photo(message):
    tb.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'upload_photo')
    img = open('out.jpg', 'rb')
    tb.send_photo(message.chat.id, img, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
    img.close()

tb.polling()

while True:
    time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: So we need to download whole file into local folder before uploading to Telegram after all. Is there any way to reduce the image size while downloading, given I run the script completely on my machine?

Comment: I don't know what it is exactly what you are trying to make, but I am sure there are ways to compress images with python, only not _while_ downloading. And make sure to delete the image from your computer when you do not need the file anymore.

Comment: My code here - I believe as I'm new to python - doesn't require to download the image into local folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32441772/1097372

Answer (score 2):

```
elif 'Hi' in text:
    reply(img=urllib2.urlopen('img url').read())
```